# XSLT use single quot

Tags: xml, xslt

My desired XML output is

```
<ziomrequest>
    <TICKET_ID>$filter=(CDOC_ID eq '1234')</TICKET_ID>
</ziomrequest>
```

However I am unable to figure out how to enclose 1234 inside single quot's.
I tried using the `&quot;`, but it gave me double quote.  My requirement is to have single quotes.
I am using the below XSLT:

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <ziomrequest>
         <TICKET_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('$filter=(CDOC_ID eq ',/ziomrequest/TICKET_ID,')')"/>
         </TICKET_ID>
      </ziomrequest>
   </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Define and use a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$filter=(CDOC_ID eq ', $apos, 
                             /ziomrequest/TICKET_ID, $apos,';)')"/>
```

### XPath 2.0+

Use double `'` characters:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('$filter=(CDOC_ID eq ''',
                             /ziomrequest/TICKET_ID, ''')')"/>
```